# Uri.Port behaviour in different environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, port

I'm using the property `Uri.Port` in MVC 3 to get the port of my ASP.NET Development Server. However, I was wondering if, when going live on the Web, I will need the Port #.

Also, what does this property return when there is no port? My guess is that it returns 80, which is the normal HTTP Port number.

Comment: HTTP Port number: [Check this link](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1166/~/port-numbers-for-port-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

Uri.Port can never 'not' have a number, as your web browser can never 'not' connect to a port; the TCP/IP standard that your web browser uses for its communications requires a port number in order to create a connection.

When you open a URL, such as

```
    http://www.sample.com/
```

your browser picks up on there not being a port number, and simply connects to port 80 (that being the long-agreed default port number). Conversely, if you connect to

```
    http://www.sample.com:8080/
```

your browser will attempt to connect to port 8080 of www.sample.com. If a server were running at that address, it would report that Uri.Port were '8080' instead.